# What is the nature of F# exception type

Tags: exception, f#

I am learning F# and I found an interesting question.
We can use F# type exception

```
exception MyExpetion of string
```

However, when we match it, we can use the same syntax as matching a discriminated union. At the same time, it is a System.Exception. How is this done? What is the type of F# exception? I tried to search but no clear answer is found. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of exception types as a sort of "open" discriminated union, where additional constructors for the `Exception` type can be added at any time.  Therefore, as you might expect, the static type of `MyException "test"` is `Exception`, and values of type `Exception` can be matched against the pattern `MyException _`.